# How do I enable native audit logging in Cassandra 3.11?

Tags: cassandra, imperva

I Need help to enable audit logging in Cassandra 3.11 which this version not include enable audit logging and I want to read it from DAM Solution (Imperva Sonar) So I tried

1 - ECAUdit Solution

https://github.com/Ericsson/ecaudit/blob/release/c3.11/doc/install.md

2 - Enable Nodetool Scraabiblity to 1

Nothing work with me So i need help with this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "native" [audit logging](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/new/auditlogging.html) feature was added to Cassandra 4.0 ([CASSANDRA-12151](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12151)) so it is not available in earlier versions.

I don't believe the contributors to the ecAudit plugin you linked respond to questions here so you need to check the project for details on how to get help. Cheers!